# How to change password masking timing in UITextField? or It has a default behaviour

Tags: ios, uitextfield

I want to delay the password masking by some seconds.
But default timing is 3 seconds (approx.). It is not what I want.

Comment: Yes, that is the default behaviour

Comment: Is there any way to change the timing?

Comment: I guess no we can't change the timing.

Answer (score 0):

That is by default behaviour of the UITextField, when you set it to `isSecureTextEntry = true`,

the workaround is to implement the textField's `shouldChangeCharactersIn` Delegate method and can observe the textChange event, there you set a `Timer` with `TimeInterval` of you choice and after that much duration your text will be changed to secure.

Again, note that, this will not give the exact behaviour as available in UITextField for secure entries. In default it secures, one by one text as you enters, while here, it will show and hide whole text at a time, as soon as you stop entering text, it will wait for the specified time duration and then make it secure.

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {
 @IBOutlet var textField: UITextField!
  var timer: Timer?
  let timeInterval: TimeInterval = 5 // Modify it to the timeInterval of your choice.
}
```

And code for UITextFieldDelegate methods implementation is:

```
extension ViewController: UITextFieldDelegate {

func textField(_ textField: UITextField, shouldChangeCharactersIn range: NSRange, replacementString string: String) -> Bool {

        textField.isSecureTextEntry = false
        if let timer = timer {
            timer.invalidate()
        }

        timer = Timer.scheduledTimer(withTimeInterval: timeInterval, repeats: false, block: { (timer) in
            timer.invalidate()
            textField.isSecureTextEntry = true
        })

        return true
    }
}
```

Try and share your results.